# Is there any ambiguity in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Similar to ROS, reactive nitrogen species (RNS) are by-product of
>   cellular metabolism, **primarily generated from mitochondria**, and plays
>   a fundamental role in aging

When I am typing this sentence, it occurs to me whether this past participle structure "primarily generated from mitochondria" here will cause ambiguity? I don't know normally how native English speakers use this structure. Is it more typical to write like this:

> Similar to ROS, reactive nitrogen species (RNS) are by-product of
>   cellular metabolism **which are primarily generated from mitochondria**, and plays
>   a fundamental role in aging

Thanks!

Comment: The second sentence does make it more clear. Meanwhile, I would have almost said, "a by-product" or "by-products."

Comment: The verb *plays* should be in the plural (play), like *are*.

Comment: I would make two sentences.  "... is a by-product of metabolism, generated primarily from mitochondria. RNS plays a fundamental role..."

Comment: @RonaldSole I agree. *'play'* refers to RNS!